# Getting the indexes of a numpy array slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I get an array of indexes from a slice of a 2d numpy array?
For example:

```
array = np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)
section = array[1:,1:]
```

`section.shape` is `(4, 3)`. I want an array `indexes` of dimensions `(2, 4, 3)`, with the first axis being the indexes of each value from `section` in `array`.

indexes should look like:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]], 

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

The indexes are needed so that I can modify it, then index `array` with `array[indexes[0], indexes[1]]`.

I think this could be solved by slicing np.mgrid... but I'm not sure how this would be done. Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.mgrid`:

```
>>> i,j = array.shape
>>> np.mgrid[1:i,1:j]
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```